# How do I store Strings in a array and then print of the order it was put in

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want a program to take user input as in word lists, and store them in an array, take another word list store that in an array, and display the word lists in that order. So like if their words were cat,dog,mouse and the second list was car,sheep,cow it would print out, the lists stop when the user enters "XXX"

```
0; cat
1; mouse
2; cat

0; car
1; sheep
2; cow
```

How do I do this  I have to use arrays.. and I just don't understand. I have this so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ClosedLab11A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 0;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);


        System.out.println("Enter the first wordlist: ");
        System.out.print("Enter a word ('XXX' to quit):");
        String word = keyboard.nextLine();


        while ( !"XXX".equals(word)){
            System.out.print("Enter a word ('XXX' to quit):");
            word = keyboard.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++);
            if (word.equals("XXX")){
                System.out.print(word);
            }


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please help us out by telling us what exactly don't you understand? Can you show us your attempt to solve this? Doing this will help us understand what assumptions you may have that are incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Use an `ArrayList<String>`, and then add the `String` elements using the `add()`method. When you iterate over it, they'll come out in the same order they were added as long as you start iterating from the `0` index up to its `size()`.

If you definitely want to go the hard way, just use a `String[]` with size enough to accommodate all the elements and keep track of the index used for adding the last element.

Whenever you need to add another element, add it at the position in the last index and increment the index. When needed, just iterate over the array starting at index `0` up to the last used index, the elements will come out in the same order that was used for insertion.

Comment: Can I store strings in that aren't arraylists only for ints?

Comment: @WinterOne of course not! you can put anything in there! where did you get that idea?!

Comment: My CSE teacher said that.. now the only problem is how to print out the numbers? 0: 1:2 etc to make it correspond.. do I use a for loop?

Comment: @WinterOne yup, just pay attention to the indexes, make sure to iterate over the part of the array you're interested in

Comment: I got the println to work to print out the word list, but I don't get how to print out the numbers ? I don't have any ints to compare it to.